# How to set to redis value if the value contain multiline?

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I am not able to set multiline value to redis? is there any better way to do?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you share an example? Are you using the CLI? If so, are you passing the command from the command line or are you typing it in REPL mode?

Comment: I am using nc. Trying to escape \r\n.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - perhaps you can add the actual thing you're trying to do to the question itself? In any case, I don't see why you'd need to escape that, e.g. `printf "*2\r\n\$4\r\nPING\r\n\$4\r\nYO\r\n\r\n" | nc localhost 6379` works for me.

Comment: Something like this is not working. printf `"*1\r\n\$35set key MyGroup\r\nGroupA\r\nGroupB\r\n" | nc localhost 6379`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

Just do like

```
printf "*3\r\n\$3\r\nset\r\n\$3\r\nfoo\r\n\$15\r\nMyGroup\r\nGroupA\r\n" | nc localhost 6379
```

* Specify the rows
\$ count the character